# Error when I'm updating

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, update-manager

I have some errors when I'm running `sudo apt update`
This is what it says:

````
Hit:2 http://my.mirrors.thegigabit.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease          
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://my.mirrors.thegigabit.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease        
Hit:6 http://my.mirrors.thegigabit.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease         
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:8 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                      
Get:9 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease [5,588 B]                           
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease       
Hit:13 https://brinkervii.gitlab.io/grapejuice/repositories/debian universal InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.```

Can someone help me?
````

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources; meaning all security checks are on you to perform.  That PPA doesn't provide support for anything beyond *disco* or 19.04; so did you perform any security checks?  It should not have been added as it provides no support for *focal* or 20.04.  https://launchpad.net/~morphis/+archive/ubuntu/anbox-support

Comment: Thx, i fixed it by running ```sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:morphis/anbox-support```